# Unfocusing textbox with jQuery when key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox that displays an alert when you click outside the textbox. I'm trying to also display the alert if the user presses Enter. Here's what I have:

```
<input id="txtInput" type="text" onblur="alert('Hello');" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtInput").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

If I click inside the textbox and then click outside it, the alert shows correctly.

But if I'm inside the textbox and push Enter, it shows the alert - when I dismiss the alert, another alert shows (I assume because onblur is being called on the textbox).

Why doesn't calling `$(this).blur()` remove the focus from the textbox? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/ERdaa/ with your example. It works as expected in Chrome on OSX. I do not experience the issue you mention.

Comment: what browser and what version of jquery are you testing on?? your code works fine with chrome/jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Chrome version 25 and jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: You are 100% correct then, in 1.8.3 I see that behavior. See below for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this works, I can't tell you, but if you remove the `onblur` event from your HTML and put it into your js, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/ERdaa/4/

```
$("#txtInput").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
    }
}).blur(function(){
     alert('Hello');
});
```

[edit] cleaned up code to use chaining instead of using selector twice.